# Custom fonts : @Font-Face issues in chrome,firefox

Tags: css

I downloaded a font and generated font-face css using font-squirrel. 
The font is displayed properly in IE,Opera but in chrome , firefox & safari it looks small and something totally different... 
Is there anything that i need to change ??

```
@font-face {

font-family: 'LektonRegular';
src: url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url(myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.ttf)  format('truetype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.svg#LektonRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: I use it in this way ...  h6{ 
color:#D8D2CE; 
font:11pt;
letter-spacing:-1px; 
font-weight:bold; 
font-family: LektonRegular;
}

Comment: Try putting the font name in quotes. If that doesn't work, another CSS rule is overriding that font family.

Comment: yeah tried with quotes same problem... there is no other rule overriding the h6 tag :(

Comment: Then it may be the fact that you are using font:11pt instead of font-size.

Comment: ok i figured out the problem.. the size of the font in h6 in IE is different and size of h6 in chrome is different .. hmm :|

Comment: thanks even changed font:11pt to font-size:11pt .. it worked :)